# Could someone help me understand this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> [...] Carlos Slim, for example, keeps track of his huge business empire using handwritten notes, which he keeps in a series of meticulously cross-referenced journals.

I didn't understand this part: **meticulously cross-referenced journals**

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you know what each one of those words means, individually?

Comment: Only "meticulously" and "journals".

Comment: A cross-reference is a note (in a source of information) that directs you to look in another part to find what you want, or tells you that there may be relevant information in another section. Mr Slim doesn't just jot things down as they happen, but makes careful notes to help him to keep track of all his business information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you have trouble understanding 'cross-referenced' as it modifies 'journals'.

A journal that's cross-referenced is one where entries in the journal reference each other.  Consider an encyclopedia - the article for 'volcano' probably references the articles for 'mountain', 'earthquake', 'lava', and 'plate tectonics', among other possibilities.

Similarly, the entries in Mr. Slim's journals reference each other.  For example, a meeting he had in 2019 - about a new business venture in country X dealing with industry Y - might reference an unrelated vacation trip he took to country X in 2012, as well as all of his involvements in industry Y.

[Cross-Reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross-reference) (Merriam-Webster)

noun definition:

> a notation or direction at one place (as in a book or filing system) to pertinent information at another place

verb definition 2:

> to research, verify, or organize by means of cross-references

The quoted term 'cross-referenced' is the adjective form (from the past tense of the verb).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In simple words: journals those are *very carefully maintained and verified from different resources*.